# After combining JS into one file, slick is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slick.js

I have combined some JS files as below:

combined.js

```
/* jQuery-1.11.0-min.js code*/
/* slick.js code*/
/* jQuery-migrate-v1.2.1.js code*/
/* other.js code*/
```

Cannot paste code here as character limit exceeds.

They include jQuery-1.11.0, slick.min.js and some other JS files. But slick.js doesn't work.

It works if I load jQuery and slick.js separately.

Any Clues?/

Comment: How do you combine the files? How do the first file end, and second one starts in the combined file?

Answer (score 1):

It may be that there are conflicting variables between the files. Try using a bundling tool like parcel.js or webpack.

https://parceljs.org/